# Connection between $\dim\operatorname{Im}(A+B)$ and $\dim \operatorname{Im}(A)\cap\operatorname{Im}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for two $n\times n$- matrices $A$ and $B$ we have
$$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)=\dim\operatorname{Im}(A+B)\leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) - \dim \operatorname{Im}(A)\cap \operatorname{Im}(B).$$

But is there another relation between  $\dim\operatorname{Im}(A+B)$ and $\dim \operatorname{Im}(A)\cap\operatorname{Im}(B)$? I'm looking for something that connects these two but that is rather an equality than an inequality.

Comment: By $A$ and $B$, you mean the representative matrices of two different linear transformations $T_A$ and $S_B$?

Comment: @Itay4 yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ (over a field of characteristic $\ne2$), with a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. For $1\le k\le n$, consider the maps
$$
f_k\colon V\to V,
\qquad
f_k(v_i)=\begin{cases}
v_i & \text{if $1\le i\le k$} \\[6px]
0 & \text{if $k<i\le n$}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
g\colon V\to V,
\qquad
g(v_i)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $i=1$} \\[6px]
v_i & \text{if $1<i\le n$}
\end{cases}
$$
extended by linearity.

Observe that the rank of $f_k+g$ is $n$ for every $k$. Moreover
\begin{gather}
\dim(\operatorname{Im}f_1\cap\operatorname{Im}g)=0 \\
\dim(\operatorname{Im}f_2\cap\operatorname{Im}g)=1 \\
\dim(\operatorname{Im}f_3\cap\operatorname{Im}g)=2 \\
\vdots
\end{gather}

With different choices of $g$ you can get the rank of the sum smaller than $n$.

This shows that you cannot establish a general relation between the rank of the sum and the dimension of the intersection of the images.